# Why is Chrome not allowing to save password and autofill forms?

Tags: google-chrome

I am unable to save password and any other form information on Google Chrome on Windows. I cannot enable the advanced setting for form autofill as shown in the picture below.

[image]

How can I change this?

Comment: are you using a chromebook ? or a supervised account ?

Answer (score 0):

That icon indicates that the autofill and password save options are enforced by group Administrator using group Policies.

If this is part of a domain then there's nothing much you can do(save for asking your Administrator to relax this setting)